# How to Deleting a line TableLayout at runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to be as soon as possible and explain my problem in the best way.

I'm working with fragments on android, and one of the fragments own a TableLayout I'll filling with runtime objects. The line layout is being inflated to .xml separated which has a button. Clicking this button would like the line were excluded from the table.

The doubt would be, how will I pass this function to the button if it is created during the application run?

This is the line layout:

- ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/bordas">

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/tv_numero_sacola"
  style="@style/TextoCorpoTabela" />

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/tv_peso_sacola"
  style="@style/TextoCorpoTabela" />

  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/bt_excluir"
  android:layout_width="40dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_lixeira" />


  </TableRow>
  ```

This is the method that populates the table:

- ```
  public void preencheTabelaSacola() {
  TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) viewPai.findViewById(R.id.tl_sacola);
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  TableRow novaLinha = (TableRow) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_linha_tabela_sacola, null);

  TextView tvNumeroSacola = (TextView) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.tv_numero_sacola);
  tvNumeroSacola.setText(numeroSacola);

  TextView tvPesoSacola = (TextView) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.tv_peso_sacola);
  float peso = itemSacola.getPeso();
  tvPesoSacola.setText(String.format("%.2f", peso));

  ImageButton excluir = (ImageButton) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.bt_excluir);
  excluir.setOnClickListener(this);

  Toast.makeText(contexto, "Sacola " + numeroSacola + " Pesando " + pesoSacola + "(Kg) foi adicionada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  //Adiciona Linha
  tableLayout.addView(novaLinha);
  }
  ```

Comment: I thought of something such as adding a method in OnlickListner with some function like: 
`tableLayout.removeViewsInLayout(1, tableLayout.getChildCount() - 1); `
but I can not implement =(

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id of the view at runtime and then setting the onClickListener on the Button

```
public class Utils {
private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);
public static int generateViewId() { 
    for (;;) { 
        final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
        int newValue = result + 1;
        if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
        if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
            return result;
        } 
    } 
} 

}
```

Now set the Id of the view in following way e.g

```
                      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) 
                      {

                           textViewId= Utils.generateViewId();

                        }
                      else 
                      { 
                           textViewId= View.generateViewId();
                        }
```

t

Comment: I thought of something such as adding a method in OnlickListner with some function like:

tableLayout.removeViewsInLayout(1, tableLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

but I can not implement =(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem in a very simple way as had imagined:

```
     ImageButton excluir = (ImageButton) novaLinha.findViewById(R.id.bt_excluir);
    excluir.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       novaLinha.setVisibility(viewPai.GONE);
                                   }
                               });
```